# Building for local and production in IntelliJ using Maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I have a simple spring mvc app, using maven with intellij.

How do you go about creating seperate files for both production and development?

e.g. say I want to set a production and development mysql connection string for nhibernate?

How can I have it such that when I build it will take the correct file to use to grab configuration information? (and any advice on naming conventions for the files?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an ant task is pretty straight forward for this.

First, create a couple profiles under `<project>` in your `pom`:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>build-dev</id>
    <activation>
      <!-- <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault> -->
      <property>
        <name>env</name>
        <value>dev</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <config.name>config.dev.properties</config.name>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>build-prod</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>env</name>
        <value>prod</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <config.name>config.prod.properties</config.name>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then use the `maven-antrun-plugin`

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.properties"/>
            <copy file="src/main/resources/${config.name}" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.properties"/>
            <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.dev.properties"/>
            <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.prod.properties"/>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Now you just specify the profile you want when you run `mvn`. If you want a default, uncomment and place the:

```
<!-- <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault> -->
```

section in the profile you want by default. As it is, the build will fail on the ant task if neither is specified.

Comment: sort of off-topic, but I read another post of yours regarding getting 15K requests per second, do you have an email I could contact you with? very curious!

Answer (score 2):

There are a ton of ways to go about this.

In general, things like DB connection strings can go into property files, and replaced in the Spring XML configuration files using a [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html). One common-ish trick is to then create a custom implementation that looks for a `-D` startup parameter, a user name, a machine name, etc. that can be used to decide which property file to actually use.

The same trick can be used for the Spring configuration files as well by creating an implementation of an XmlWebApplicationContext (? I can never remember what to subclass) that adds/modifies the default [getConfigLocations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.html#getConfigLocations%28%29) to add, say, files prefaced with a user or machine name, `-D` startup parameter value, and so on.

Btw, you're not using NHibernate if you're using Java, you're using Hibernate.

*Edit* Brian's approach is one of those "tons of ways", I just like to keep it configurable without building, i.e., dynamic based on arbitrary "local" conditions, etc. so I can swap things out really easily.

Comment: Eh, I'm a big fan of "Keep it simple, stupid" is all. I actually found that originally on the maven site as a recommended way to handle different config files; can't seem to find it now though.

Comment: @BrianRoach As long as your needs never change, developers don't have to make any settings of their own, and you're only deploying a bounded set of configs, sure. I haven't had that happen in real life, but YMMV. Having things trivially overrideable in one way or another has saved my teams tons of time--these subclasses are literally a half-dozen/dozen lines long.

Comment: I've never found a need to do anything else. In 20 years. That being said, I don't do web or desktop stuff, and in general do work with a fairly narrow set of parameters in any given application. I'm guessing my mileage may be in kilometers ;)

Comment: @BrianRoach I doubt you've used Maven or Spring for 20 years ;) Just keeping dev-specific DB settings pays the price of admission; haven't *not* used it on a Spring project in 5yrs. But even back in the day we generally had user-specific configuration needs along side default/standard configs. Let alone heterogeneous cluster deploys :/

Comment: I knew there was another reason I didn't use spring :) Aside from that, what I mean to say is that I've just never found configuration files / management a daunting task. And I'm still kinda "meh" on maven. The dependency management stuff is alright, but on the whole it seems to like making very simple things very (overly)complicated.  Of course, using m4 or any of the other GNU tools was never a lot of fun either.

Comment: @BrianRoach For simple usecases, Maven is awesome. Everything else... not so much. Spring's malleability is its greatest feature-because of that, I haven't found configuration daunting either, even under pretty twisted conditions.